# How to get a shell inside a POD instead of container running inside the POD

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to get a shell inside a running POD instead of container running inside the POD ?
kubectl exec or rsh open a shell inside a running container not the POD.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. A pod is kubernetes concept and does not provide such ability. A pod can consist of one or more containers, and the pod describes what to be run and how in the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. what you are trying to do is not possible. Pod is just to manage containers. and Pod must contain at least one container.

Answer (score 0):

My predecessors are right, you cannot shell inside a running POD. I suggest getting familiar with the [official documentation regarding Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) in order to get a better understanding of this particular concept:

> Pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can
> create and manage in Kubernetes.
>
> A Pod (as in a pod of whales or pea pod) is a group of one or more
> containers, with shared storage/network resources, and a specification
> for how to run the containers.

You can find more info regarding [using](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#using-pods) or [working with them](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#working-with-pods) as well as other details like [resource sharing and communication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#resource-sharing-and-communication).